# iOS - PHP APN delivered but no notification

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, phonegap, apns-php

I've been trying for days now to push notifications from my php script to my iPhone with no luck!

I've tried numerous php scripts, generating pem certificates etc!

When I run the script I get "Delivered Message to APNS" but nothing comes through to my phone.

Also I'm running this as a sandbox and my app is in development.

```
  <?php 
  $tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
  $tPort = 2195;
  $tCert = 'push.pem';
  $tPassphrase = 'password';
  $tToken = 'cps2OsFjufQ:APA91xEjcjQK368UOf6XMya8huaITdl_3PrJXPB-7NQCGUu30Z7djHQPKcDCvFkMN-qLZiIA_7ZCV_cpv3zsJh5EtLJ4BpZD6mQ4B6ZYDcoLOrKLVVY67iCcS7UJ4qA2mwsvdgpJ7C6w';

  $tSound = 'default';
  $tPayload = 'APNS payload';
  $tBody['aps'] = array(
    'badge' => +1,
    'alert' => 'Test notification',
    'sound' => 'default'
  );

 $tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;
 $tBody = json_encode ($tBody);

 $tContext = stream_context_create ();
 stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert',      $tCert);
 stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase',      $tPassphrase);


 $tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort,      $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,      $tContext);
 if (!$tSocket)
 exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
 $tMsg = chr(1) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $tToken) . pack('n', strlen($tBody)) . $tBody; 


 $tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));
 if ($tResult)
     echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
 else
     echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
 fclose ($tSocket);
 ?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but in my code, my `fwrite` message looks like this: `$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;`

Comment: Nope doesnt make a difference - still not recieving anything - its doing my help in!